# I want to upload my dist folder to Github and then sync it to my DirectAdmin deployment... How do I set it up?

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, directadmin

I have managed to setup my Github private repo, but I want to sync it to my DirectAdmin so I can deploy it from there and have everything synced up.
[my git dashboard within directadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djWp1.png)

I tried using SSH and HTTPS, but I don't have the best understanding of those technologies so I may have done it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**To sync your GitHub repository with your DirectAdmin server try this steps   using SSH method :**

-To generate SSH Key on DirectAdmin:Log in to DirectAdmin, go to "SSH Manager," and generate an SSH key pair.

-Add SSH Key to GitHub:Copy the public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to GitHub's SSH settings.

-Clone Repository on DirectAdmin:SSH into your DirectAdmin server and clone your GitHub repo using this code:

```
git clone git@github.com:your-username/your-repository.git
```

-Pull Changes:Update your code on the server with:

```
git pull origin main
```

Comment: Wow, this makes sense... I'm going to try this out pretty soon and will let you know if it works or not. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to update this thread, but yes, it did work. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you! Don't hesitate to reach out if you encounter any issues. Happy coding!